# Custom Post Type loop WITH pagination on front-page.php

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I have been googling and searching for a few days now and many of the solutions I've come across simply won't work. Please be patient if you have seen this question before.

I have a custom post type called "food" and I want to show the 9 most recent posts on front-page.php and have the pagination work. I can only seem to get variations of this to work. The closest I've gotten is where the pagination will work, but when you proceed to page 2, index.php is used to display the paginated pages.

This is my loop:

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('showposts=9&post_type=food'.'&paged='.$paged); 

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>

<h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
<?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>

<?php
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
?>
```

I will love you forever and ever if you can help me.

**EDIT: I believe I solved my problem. My theme was missing archive.php (currently in local development so I just hadn't gotten around to creating it yet) and I guess it was throwing everything off. Thank you for your time!**

Comment: You are supposed to use index.php and route using the correct URL structure or querystring to select a category or posts by tag (or other). That's why there is no option to provide an alternative php file name in `previous_posts_link()` or `next_posts_link()`. `front-page.php` within the template folder would be **included** by index.php given the correct scenario, that's why it would exist.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Nigel. So are you saying that page 2 for pagination is SUPPOSE to be using the index.php page? Sorry if this is suppose to be obvious. I'm relatively new to custom theming.

Comment: Everything routes through the root index.php which is `yoursite.com/index.php` The template files are pulled in. It would be worth reading a tutorial about creating or modifying a template if you don't want to struggle.

Comment: What is your theme name? Now a days every theme has pagination option. You can use wordpress default function to simple pagination : `next_posts_link('NEXT>>')` and `previous_posts_link('<<PREV')`. And if your theme already have a pagination i can provide a code which will show all custom posts with your normal post types.